# How to solve the warnings that occurs while using the command "yarn install" in react js

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint, prettier, babel-eslint

I'm working on a react js app. There I build a basic application without using create-react-app command.
So when I'm using "yarn install" command I'm getting these warning messages. I tried to solve the same but unable to do so.

This is the warnings which I'm getting:-

> `yarn install v1.22.19 info No lockfile found. [1/4] Resolving packages... [2/4] Fetching packages... [3/4] Linking dependencies... warning " > @babel/eslint-parser@7.19.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^7.5.0 || ^8.0.0". warning " > eslint-config-prettier@8.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@>=7.0.0". warning " > eslint-plugin-import@2.26.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^2 || ^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7.2.0 || ^8". warning " > eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6.6.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7 || ^8". warning " > eslint-plugin-react@7.31.11" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7 || ^8". [4/4] Building fresh packages... success Saved lockfile. Done in 164.19s.`[Image with warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAKWK.png)

I am trying to remove all the warning messages.

Comment: try installing the same package again
Does it still gives that warning?

If you read your warning it says that there is not lockfile meaning therewas not yarn.lock file at the time of installing but at the end it tells that it created a new lockfile.

Comment: @CircuitPlanet the lockfile was created when the "yarn install" command gets executed but the warning are still there.
Even after running the same command when lockfile is there the warning message is being displayed.

Comment: did you try `yarn add eslint`

Answer (score 0):

They are harmless and can be ignored for most of the cases
but if they still cause you trouble and you want to resolve them then just install it by:

```
yarn add eslint
```

as for the `lockfile` warning it will be resolved after you install and package

Try:

```
yarn add
```